# How to get remaining users of a group after creating a subgroup of that group in Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$groupId = 3;
$users = User::whereHas('groups', function ($query) use ($groupId) {
$query->where('group_id', $groupId);
})->doesntHave('subgroups')->get();
```

Above code getting users of a group and that users which are not added in any subgroup..
What i want?
I want:

1. As i have a group of 10 users
2. I create a subgroup of that group and add 5 users out of 10 in subgroup
3. Now i want to create another subgroup of remaining 5 users, so i need to show only 5 users that are not added in any subgroup of that specific group... So how i will get that remaining 5 users to show
4. Users, group, subgroups all have many-many relationship with each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the groups table, is the primary key named 'group_id'?
because if not then the where in the query should be:

```
$query->where('groups.id', $groupId);
```

now: give me all the users that belongs to this group and their subgroups doesn't 
belongs to this group:

```
$users = User::whereHas('groups', function ($query) use ($groupId) {
        $query->where('group_id', $groupId);})
        ->whereDoesntHave('subgroups', function ($query) use ($groupId) {
            $query->whereHas('groups', function ($q) use ($groupId) {
                $q->where('group_id', '=', $groupId);
            });
        })->get();
```

Comment: Facing error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting ')'

Comment: Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: should be something wrong in the relation, are you sure there is a many to many relation between User and Subgroup?

Comment: ohh..! sorry dear i got that ... Its working fine now thanks